# Pyplot subplots with equal absolute scale but different limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm not sure my wording is correct, but what I am trying to do is create a figure of two subplots, where the two plots have different limits, but their size is such that the physical scale (as in, y-distance per centimeter of figure height) is the same. To clarify, lets say subplot 1 shows data from -3 to 3 and subplot 2 shows data from -1 to 1. I want to have them below one another in such a way that the height of subplot2 (excluding ticks, just everything inside the frame) is exactly one third of subplot 1.

My attempt was as follows:

```
from matplotlib import gridspec
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,2, 101)
y1 = 3*np.cos(x*np.pi)
y2 = np.cos(x*np.pi)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 6)) 
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(8, 1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0:6,0])
ax1.plot(x, y1, c='orange')
ax1.set_ylim(-3, 3)
ax1.set_xticks([], [])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[6:,0])
ax2.plot(x, y2, c='green')
ax2.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax2.set_xticks([0, 1, 2])
ax2.set_xticklabels([r'0', r'0.5', r'1'])
ax2.set_xlabel(r'$n_g$ (2e)')
plt.tight_layout()
fig.text(-0.025, 0.5, 'Frequency (GHz)', ha='center', va='center', rotation='vertical', size=18)
```

which produces the figure below, but as you can see (although you have to look closely) the range -1 to 1 in the second subplot is compressed (takes up less height) than the range -1 to 1 in subplot 1. I'm guessing this is because of the space between the two subplots.

*Note that I'm using gridspec because I plan on adding another column of subplots with interesting aspect ratio's and its own labels and limits. I didn't know how to add a global ylabel in a more elegant way, if someone was wondering.*

[image]

Comment: Does it need to be dynamic (i.e. if you zoom on either subplot, the fraction of figure it occupies changes)?

Comment: @Leporello it does not need to be dynamic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `height_ratios` of the gridspec to match the range of the limits.

```
from matplotlib import gridspec
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,2, 101)
y1 = 3*np.cos(x*np.pi)
y2 = np.cos(x*np.pi)

ylim1 = -3,3
ylim2 = -1,1

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 6), constrained_layout=True) 
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[np.diff(ylim1)[0], 
                                            np.diff(ylim2)[0]], figure=fig)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
ax1.plot(x, y1, c='orange')
ax1.set_ylim(ylim1)
ax1.set_xticks([], [])

ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1,0])
ax2.plot(x, y2, c='green')
ax2.set_ylim(ylim2)
ax2.set_xticks([0, 1, 2])
ax2.set_xticklabels([r'0', r'0.5', r'1'])
ax2.set_xlabel(r'$n_g$ (2e)')

plt.show()
```